# Set Visibility By ID

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pass the treatmentItem id into the deleteTreat link so that it will set the visibility in the database to 0 but I am unsure how to pass the id for the section I want.

**HTML View:**

```
<div class="treatmentItem" id="1">
<div class="editName edit_text"> name</div>
<div class="deleteTreat"><a href="#"> Delete </a></div>
<div class="editPrice edit_text">price</div>
<div class="editBlurb edit_text">blurb</div>
<div class="hr"></div>
```

**PHP View:**

```
  public function renderAdminCategory($iCatID){  // Function to View Treatment Content

           $category = new Category();
           $category->load($iCatID);



           $CategoryOutput = '';
           $CategoryOutput .='<div class="clear"></div><!--end of clear-->';
           $CategoryOutput .='<div id="treatmentsContent"><!--Displaying Treatments from selected Treatment category -->';

           $aSubCategories = $category->getSubCategories();    // This stores information from getSubCategories inside aSubCategories

               foreach($aSubCategories as $subID=>$oSubCat){    // The Category
                   $name = $oSubCat->getSubCatName();            // This retrieves the Name out of the SubCatObject

                   $CategoryOutput .='<!--';
                   $CategoryOutput .=$name;
                   $CategoryOutput .='--><h2 class="categoryName">'."\n";
                   $CategoryOutput .=$name.'</h2>'."\n";
                   $CategoryOutput .='<div class="break"></div>'."\n";
                   $treatments = $oSubCat->getTreatments();



                       foreach($treatments as $treatmentID=>$oTreatment){    // The Treatment
                           $name = $oTreatment->getTreatmentName();        // Getting the TreatmentName from the treatment object - oTreatment
                           $price = $oTreatment->getTreatmentPrice();
                           $blurb = $oTreatment->getTreatmentBlurb();
                           $id = $oTreatment->getTreatmentID();
                           //$subCatId = $oTreatment->getSubID();

                           $delete = new Treatment();
                           $delete->deleteTreatment($id);

                           //$CategoryOutput .='<div class="treatmentClear"</div>';
                           $CategoryOutput .='<div class="treatmentItem" id="'.$id.'">'."\n";
                           $CategoryOutput .='<div class="editName edit_text">'.$name.'</div>'."\n";
                           $CategoryOutput .='<div class="deleteTreat"><a href="delete.php?id='. $row[ID] .' "> Delete </a></div>';
                           $CategoryOutput .='<div class="editPrice edit_text">'.$price.'</div>'."\n";
                           $CategoryOutput .='<div class="editBlurb edit_text">'.str_replace("\n",'<br/>',htmlentities($blurb)).'</div>'."\n";
                           $CategoryOutput .='<div class="hr"></div>'."\n";
                           $CategoryOutput .='</div><!-- end of treatmentItem-->';
                       }

               }
               //'.$delete->deleteTreatment($id).'
           $CategoryOutput .='</div><!--end of treatmentscontent-->';
           return $CategoryOutput;            

       }
```

**Delete Function**

```
public function deleteTreatment($iTreatmentID){

       global $database;

           $sQuery = "UPDATE treatments SET visible=0 WHERE treatmentID=".$iTreatmentID;

           $resultTreatment = $database->query($sQuery);

       echo "Successfully Deleted";

   }
```

Comment: in delete.php $_GET['id'] will have the id to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $CategoryOutput .='<div class="deleteTreat"><a href="delete.php?id='. $id .' "> Delete </a></div>';
```

not `$row[ID]` but `$id`

Also

```
 $delete = new Treatment();
 $delete->deleteTreatment($id);
```

This will still show your treatment even if it's deleted or set to zero. You need to call this BEFORE you get the listings (as i assume that  `$oSubCat->getTreatments();` is fetching from database for everything that is visible)

```
  $delete = new Treatment();
  $delete->deleteTreatment($id);
   //then you get avalable treatmants
  $treatments = $oSubCat->getTreatments();`
```

Now, I assume that delete.php calls the function that display the treatments

In other words: your link has to be the same file that is displaying the data and calling  a renderAdminCategory($catID) . So you have to parse AND  the $icatID in the link. As such

```
public function renderAdminCategory($iCatID){  // Function to View Treatment Content

           $category = new Category();
           $category->load($iCatID);



           $CategoryOutput = '';
           $CategoryOutput .='<div class="clear"></div><!--end of clear-->';
           $CategoryOutput .='<div id="treatmentsContent"><!--Displaying Treatments from selected Treatment category -->';

           $aSubCategories = $category->getSubCategories();    // This stores information from getSubCategories inside aSubCategories

               foreach($aSubCategories as $subID=>$oSubCat){    // The Category
                   $name = $oSubCat->getSubCatName();            // This retrieves the Name out of the SubCatObject

                   $CategoryOutput .='<!--';
                   $CategoryOutput .=$name;
                   $CategoryOutput .='--><h2 class="categoryName">'."\n";
                   $CategoryOutput .=$name.'</h2>'."\n";
                   $CategoryOutput .='<div class="break"></div>'."\n";

                    if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])
                    {
                    $delete = new Treatment();
                    $delete->deleteTreatment($_REQUEST['id']); //get the request parameter
                   }
                  //then you get avalable treatmants
                    $treatments = $oSubCat->getTreatments();



                       foreach($treatments as $treatmentID=>$oTreatment){    // The Treatment
                           $name = $oTreatment->getTreatmentName();        // Getting the TreatmentName from the treatment object - oTreatment
                           $price = $oTreatment->getTreatmentPrice();
                           $blurb = $oTreatment->getTreatmentBlurb();
                           $id = $oTreatment->getTreatmentID();
                           //$subCatId = $oTreatment->getSubID();

                           $delete = new Treatment();
                           $delete->deleteTreatment($id);

                           //$CategoryOutput .='<div class="treatmentClear"</div>';
                           $CategoryOutput .='<div class="treatmentItem" id="'.$id.'">'."\n";
                           $CategoryOutput .='<div class="editName edit_text">'.$name.'</div>'."\n";
                           $CategoryOutput .='<div class="deleteTreat"><a href="renderAdminCategory.php?id='. $id .'&catID='.$iCatID.' "> Delete </a></div>';
//we added catID and  this link will point to the file that is displayinf the data and callign this function
                               $CategoryOutput .='<div class="editPrice edit_text">'.$price.'</div>'."\n";
                               $CategoryOutput .='<div class="editBlurb edit_text">'.str_replace("\n",'<br/>',htmlentities($blurb)).'</div>'."\n";
                               $CategoryOutput .='<div class="hr"></div>'."\n";
                               $CategoryOutput .='</div><!-- end of treatmentItem-->';
                           }

                   }
                   //'.$delete->deleteTreatment($id).'
               $CategoryOutput .='</div><!--end of treatmentscontent-->';
               return $CategoryOutput;            

           }
```

Also make sure to escape values in update function

```
 $sQuery = "UPDATE treatments SET visible=0 WHERE treatmentID=".mysql_real_escape_string($iTreatmentID);
```

Comment: The above code is being "successful" and making things un visible but when I clicked to do it actually turns each treatment of the category invisible instead of the one requested.